# $interpolate an array instead of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way I can use Angular's `$interpolate` with an array instead of an object?

Example code:

```
var exp = $interpolate('Hello {{name}}!');
var res = exp({name: "foo"});

var exp2 = $interpolate('Hello {{0}}!');
var res2 = exp2(["foo"]);

console.log(res); // Hello foo
console.log(res2); // Hello 0  <--- Should be "Hello foo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var exp2 = $interpolate('Hello {{this[0]}}!');
var res2 = exp2(["foo"]);
console.log(res2);
```

Note: only works with angular 1.3.x and up